# Should I worry about DDMS console log messages "Can't bind to local nnnn for debugger"?

Tags: eclipse, android, android-emulator

I'm new to Android programming (and Eclipse IDE and Android emulator).  I've got Hello World and some of Notepad working, but I'm still constantly getting quite a few DDMS console log messages (shown below) about not being able to bind locals for debugger.

```
[2010-05-29 21:03:16 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8601 for debugger
[2010-05-29 21:05:26 - Device] Failed to delete temporary package: device (emulator-5556) request rejected: device not found
[2010-05-29 21:06:47 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8600 for debugger
[2010-05-29 21:07:05 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8601 for debugger
[2010-05-29 21:07:05 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8602 for debugger
```

And so on. Is this a problem?  Can I get rid of these messages somehow?

Answer (score 11):

In Eclipse, goto

1) Windows->Preference

2) Expand **Android** menu in the side of the Preference Window.

3) Now select DDMS from it.

4) Then Set the Base local debugger port to "8601" and enable "Use ADBHOST" checkbox and the ABDHOST value should be "127.0.0.1".

5) Click apply and ok.

6) Now you have to restart your ADB, for this you have to login as root user(Assuming linux user) and navigate to Platfrom tools folder of your Android SDK. Then execute,

```
 ./adb kill-server
 ./adb start-server
```

You will be able to see the message "Daemon started Successfully" . If not repeat step 6 once again until you see the success message.

Comment: doesn't work :(, I use windows 8, avg antivirus and eclipse ADT version 22.3.0, any suggestions ?, thanks !.

Answer (score 2):

You can get rid of the the messages by adding following to your hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

ps. hosts file can be found from c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
    or if you are on linux /etc/hosts

Comment: Helps, but I have to remove the other stuff with in that file. PS: do not forget to run adb kill-server; adb start-server

Comment: You should check out this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318738/i-get-error-in-ddmscant-bind-to-local-8600-for-debugger-why)

Answer (score 1):

In my situation the problem has been solved by a uninstalling all Java 7. The debugger is now working again!