# Android Studio can't connect to debug, I can't to find the process by pid

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

Android Studio can't connect to debug devices.
I use windows

```
Connecting to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
```

I think that there is process occupy the port "8600"
When I execute`netstat -ano|findstr 8600` in CMD, I find this

```
TCP 127.0.0.1:8600 0.0.0.0 LISTENING 1948
```

the process PID is 1948
but when I execute`taskkill /f /pid 1948`to kill the process by it's PID,
it return me that no process's pid is 1948
I can't debug in eclipse either, the port 8601 is occupied too;
someone know how to solve that?

Comment: Have you tried restarting ADB? Looks like there's a similar thread over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318738/eclipse-ddms-error-cant-bind-to-local-8600-for-debugger

Comment: Yes,but it doesn't work,I excute adb get-state,and try adb kill-server and start-server.

Comment: You don't have eclipse and Android Studio running at the same time do you?

Comment: Yes,I close all of them! It's Strange!

Comment: Finally I find the problem, Because of android L 5.0 used ART, so In ART model, debug app becomes very slow(I don't know why). If change the Runtime to dalvik , the problem is solved!