# Android Studio unable to run project on device?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I am getting the following error. I couldn't find why this happens on the internet either.

```
ddms: Can't bind to local 8601 for debugger
ddmlib: Broken pipe
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:29)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:69)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:40)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:336)
    at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:675)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:342)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:521)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:847)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:815)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.processIncomingJdwpData(DeviceMonitor.java:775)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:664)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$100(DeviceMonitor.java:46)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$3.run(DeviceMonitor.java:592)

ddmlib: Broken pipe
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:29)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:69)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:40)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:336)
    at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:675)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:342)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:521)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:847)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:815)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.processIncomingJdwpData(DeviceMonitor.java:775)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:664)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$100(DeviceMonitor.java:46)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$3.run(DeviceMonitor.java:592)
```

Note:

My device Nexus that runs 5.0.2

My android studio is 1.0.1

My platform is mac mavericks

I am just trying to run the Login template app nothing more.

Thanks

Comment: Sometimes I get the same error, but I see it, when I have AndroidStudio and eclispe opened. SO I have to close both, and open only AS, or Eclipse  to be recognised.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might have both Android studio and Eclipse open

- Close both the applications and open the one which you are going to use.
- if it didn't solve the problem the port is used by some other app so restart the system
- or else kill port using a command if the problem still remains unsolved

Comment: This also goes if you have some Eclipse-based program open, even if Eclipse as a stand-alone program isn't open. For me the culprit was the Eclipse-based "b-folders" (obscure program for safekeeping passwords and notes).

Answer (score 12):

```
adb kill-server
```

then

```
adb start-server
```

worked for me!

Answer (score 9):

Restart your computer and check

If you are using Linux try to kill the port using

`fuser -k 8601/tcp`

If you are using mac try to kill the port using

`lsof -P | grep '8601' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill`

Here is the [ref](https://superuser.com/questions/451032/how-to-kill-a-process-by-port-on-macos-a-la-fuser-k-9000-tcp) for osx

Comment: I get following error when I try in the terminal `Unknown option: k` seems like it can be helpful in unix environment.

Comment: OSX `lsof -P | grep '8601' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kil`

Answer (score 8):

There is nothing that much serious with this exception. Simply you need to unplug your USB cable from the port, restart your device and restart your Android Studio as well. Surely this exception will be removed. This worked for me, hope you will also get rid of it.

Answer (score 4):

This is just a dumb thing done by the system which as trouble finding localhost it seems. Take a look in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318738/eclipse-ddms-error-cant-bind-to-local-8600-for-debugger), many people have this question, and it's quite easy to fix.

Answer (score 4):

I am on *OS X 10.9.5*. Sometimes I get this error too. Usually I *disconnect the device ->  restart the adb* (or quit the android studio and then start again)->*connect the device* -> *run* again. [make sure you are not running adb from another eclipse/studio]

See if this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Simply using `adb kill-server` addressed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the solutions above: restarted studio, restarted devices, killed all studio processes, killed the ports listening...

Eventually the only thing that worked was File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...

Also changing the USB cable could help...