# APK failing to install

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Device is detecting in Android Studio but failing to install.

```
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
Error while Installing APK
```

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29769736/android-studio-unable-to-run-project-on-device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These issue seems to be that of the port, do the following steps-

- Restart your Android Studio.
- if it didn't solve the problem the port is used by some other app so restart the system or else kill port using a command if the problem still remains unsolved.

To kill the port, follow:

If you are using Linux try to kill the port using

fuser -k 8601/tcp

If you are using mac try to kill the port using

lsof -P | grep '8601' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill

Comment: Any idea how to kill it in Windows?

Comment: I think this SO answer should do the trick on windows- http://stackoverflow.com/a/39633428/3142342