# Error in application android to fetch data in the database postgreSQL by WebServices with Ksoap2

Tags: java, android, web-services, postgresql

First made a WebService Using axis2, which has a connection class with the database, and the class with pedidosDAO with CRUD. Using SoupUI can perform the call of methods. So far so good, I created an android app to consume these services, however this giving error when showing the data of the bank in a ListView, when I run appears (unfortunately XsaladaTeste has stopped), I had already done before and had worked but now I have been going on since time I'm not getting my logcat this buggy and not showing this log. What am I doing wrong?

**PedidosXsaladaBusca.java**

```
package com.example.xsaladateste;

public class PedidosXsaladaBusca {

    private int id_pedidos;
    private String informacao_adicionais;
    private int mesa;
    private String nome_sobrenome_cliente;
    private String nome_xsalada;
    private double total_a_pagar;

    PedidosXsaladaBusca() {

    }

    PedidosXsaladaBusca(int id_pedidos, String informacao_adicionais, int mesa, String nome_sobrenome_cliente,
            String nome_xsalada, double total_a_pagar) {

        this.id_pedidos = id_pedidos;
        this.informacao_adicionais = informacao_adicionais;
        this.mesa = mesa;
        this.nome_sobrenome_cliente = nome_sobrenome_cliente;
        this.nome_xsalada = nome_xsalada;
        this.total_a_pagar = total_a_pagar;

    }

    public int getId_pedidos() {
        return id_pedidos;
    }

    public void setId_pedidos(int id_pedidos) {
        this.id_pedidos = id_pedidos;
    }

    public String getNome_sobrenome_cliente() {
        return nome_sobrenome_cliente;
    }

    public void setNome_sobrenome_cliente(String nome_sobrenome_cliente) {
        this.nome_sobrenome_cliente = nome_sobrenome_cliente;
    }

    public int getMesa() {
        return mesa;
    }

    public void setMesa(int mesa) {
        this.mesa = mesa;
    }

    public String getInformacao_adicionais() {
        return informacao_adicionais;
    }

    public void setInformacao_adicionais(String informacao_adicionais) {
        this.informacao_adicionais = informacao_adicionais;
    }

    public double getTotal_a_pagar() {
        return total_a_pagar;
    }

    public void setTotal_a_pagar(double total_a_pagar) {
        this.total_a_pagar = total_a_pagar;
    }

    public String getNome_xsalada() {
        return nome_xsalada;
    }

    public void setNome_xsalada(String nome_xsalada) {
        this.nome_xsalada = nome_xsalada;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PedidosXsaladaBusca [id_pedidos=" + id_pedidos + ", informacao_adicionais=" + informacao_adicionais
                + ", mesa=" + mesa + ", nome_sobrenome_cliente=" + nome_sobrenome_cliente + ", nome_xsalada="
                + nome_xsalada + ", total_a_pagar=" + total_a_pagar + "]";
    }

}
```

**PedidosDAO.java**

```
    public class PedidosDAO {

    // Setando Caminhos

    private static final String URL = "http://192.168.0.1:8080/BancoParaXsalada/services/PedidosDAO?wsdl";
    private static final String nameSpace = "http://xsalada.com.br";

    // referencias ao metodos no SoapUI XML file
    private static final String BUSCAR = "buscarTodos";

    // metodo inserir no banco pelo android usando biblioteca Ksoap2

    public ArrayList<PedidosXsaladaBusca> buscarTodos() {

        ArrayList<PedidosXsaladaBusca> lista = new ArrayList<PedidosXsaladaBusca>();

        SoapObject buscarTodos = new SoapObject(nameSpace, BUSCAR);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(buscarTodos);
        envelope.implicitTypes = true;

        HttpTransportSE http = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {

            http.call("urn:" + BUSCAR, envelope);

            Vector<SoapObject> resposta = (Vector<SoapObject>) envelope.getResponse();

            for (SoapObject soapObject : resposta) {
                PedidosXsaladaBusca user = new PedidosXsaladaBusca();

                user.setId_pedidos(Integer.parseInt(soapObject.getProperty("id_pedidos").toString()));

                user.setInformacao_adicionais(soapObject.getProperty("informacao_adicionais").toString());

                user.setMesa(Integer.parseInt(soapObject.getProperty("mesa").toString()));

                user.setNome_sobrenome_cliente(soapObject.getProperty("nome_sobrenome_cliente").toString());

                user.setNome_xsalada(soapObject.getProperty("nome_xsalada").toString());

                user.setTotal_a_pagar(Double.parseDouble(soapObject.getProperty("total_a_pagar").toString()));

                lista.add(user);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

            return null;
        }

        return lista;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public ListView listaUsuario = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaPedidos);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    }

    PedidosDAO dao = new PedidosDAO();
    ArrayList<PedidosXsaladaBusca> lista = dao.buscarTodos();

    ArrayAdapter<PedidosXsaladaBusca> adpUser = new ArrayAdapter<PedidosXsaladaBusca>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lista);
    listaUsuario.setAdapter(adpUser);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, it was not code error I realized he was giving the following error: [timestamp - DDMs] Can not bind to site 8600 is debugger

then researched and solve. below is the link I found to resolve the error:

[Eclipse DDMS error "Can't bind to local 8600 for debugger"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318738/eclipse-ddms-error-cant-bind-to-local-8600-for-debugger)