# Creating data base do not work Android / Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

just getting started with android and trying to create simple data base.

Here is my code:

```
FoodMacrosTable.java
public class FoodMacrosTable {

public static final String DB_NAME = "FoodDatabase.db";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

public class FoodMacros implements BaseColumns {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "FoodMacros";


    public static final String FOOD_NAME = "Food name";
    public static final String FOOD_PROTEIN = "Amount of protein in 100g";
    public static final String FOOD_CARBS = "Amount of carbs in 100g";
    public static final String FOOD_FATS = "Amount of fats in 100g";
    public static final String FOOD_CALORIES = "Amount of calories in 100g";
    public static final String FOOD_VIT_A = "% of daily needs in 100g";

    public final String[] TABLE_COLUMNS = {FOOD_NAME,FOOD_PROTEIN,FOOD_CARBS,FOOD_FATS,FOOD_CALORIES,
            FOOD_VIT_A};

}
```

}

```
HealthyDbHanbler.java

public class HealthyDbHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public HealthyDbHandler(Context context){
    super(context,FoodMacrosTable.DB_NAME,null,FoodMacrosTable.DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + FoodMacrosTable.FoodMacros.TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
            FoodMacrosTable.FoodMacros._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            FoodMacrosTable.FoodMacros.FOOD_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            FoodMacrosTable.FoodMacros.FOOD_PROTEIN + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            FoodMacrosTable.FoodMacros.FOOD_CARBS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            FoodMacrosTable.FoodMacros.FOOD_FATS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            FoodMacrosTable.FoodMacros.FOOD_CALORIES + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            FoodMacrosTable.FoodMacros.FOOD_VIT_A + " TEXT NOT NULL );";

    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(createTable);


}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + FoodMacrosTable.FoodMacros.TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
}

public void addFood(Food food){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values =  new ContentValues();
    values.put(FoodMacrosTable.FoodMacros.FOOD_NAME,food.getFOOD_NAME());
    values.put(FoodMacrosTable.FoodMacros.FOOD_PROTEIN,food.getFOOD_PROTEIN());
    values.put(FoodMacrosTable.FoodMacros.FOOD_CARBS,food.getFOOD_CARBS());
    values.put(FoodMacrosTable.FoodMacros.FOOD_FATS,food.getFOOD_FATS());
    values.put(FoodMacrosTable.FoodMacros.FOOD_CALORIES,food.getFOOD_CALORIES());
    values.put(FoodMacrosTable.FoodMacros.FOOD_VIT_A,food.getFOOD_VIT_A());

    db.insert(FoodMacrosTable.FoodMacros.TABLE_NAME,null,values);

    db.close();
}
```

}

```
MainActivity.java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    HealthyDbHandler db = new HealthyDbHandler(this) ;
    Log.v("DBINFO","Database created");

}
```

}

Here is the error i get:
    1:42:56 PM Can't bind to local 8600 for debugger
    1:42:56 PM An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
           at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
           at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
           at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
           at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
           at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
           at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.write(JdwpPacket.java:179)
           at com.android.ddmlib.Client.send(Client.java:654)
           at com.android.ddmlib.jdwp.JdwpAgent.send(JdwpAgent.java:92)
           at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:349)
           at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:517)
           at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:573)
           at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:545)
           at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.processIncomingJdwpData(DeviceMoni... (show balloon)

Comment: I recommend creating the DB before (with SQLite tools) and deploying it as Asset in your app. Way easier.

Comment: Will try this next , but want to learn how to do it this way first

Comment: The error says Android Studio can't even start your app. The debugger does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is not about sqlite, or even your application.

Try to restart Android Studio, adb server,
reenable usb-debugging in your device, or something from related topic(if nothing helps)
[Eclipse DDMS error "Can't bind to local 8600 for debugger"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318738/eclipse-ddms-error-cant-bind-to-local-8600-for-debugger)