# Can't bind to local 8600 for debugger (error in android studio)

Tags: android

How I can solve this problem?

When I run the app it crashes.

This is the error I see in the DDMS:

```
[2017-02-08 18:53:25 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8600 for debugger[2017-02-08 18:53:25 - ddmlib] ??????? ????? ???? ??-??? ?????? ????? ????? ???
java.io.IOException: ??????? ????? ???? ??-??? ?????? ????? ????? ???
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
    at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:684)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:349)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:523)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:564)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:539)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.processIncomingJdwpData(DeviceMonitor.java:501)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:397)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$100(DeviceMonitor.java:64)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$1.run(DeviceMonitor.java:320)
```

Comment: Have you tried solutions in this question thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318738/eclipse-ddms-error-cant-bind-to-local-8600-for-debugger

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem:

> Can't bind to local 8600 for debugger

Resolved it by restarting Android Studio.

Comment: worked for me, so I have undone your negative score!