# Android Emulator (Can't bind to local 8601 for debugger)

Tags: java, android, windows, emulation

I have Windows 8, JDK 7 (7u9) and all SDK for Android.
When I try to launch Android Emulator, I have the following messages on DDMS console:

```
[2012-11-17 12:34:32 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8601 for debugger 
[2012-11-17 12:34:39 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8606 for debugger
[2012-11-17 12:34:40 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8613 for debugger
[2012-11-17 12:34:40 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8619 for debugger
[2012-11-17 12:34:40 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8632 for debugger
[2012-11-17 12:34:40 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8635 for debugger
[2012-11-17 12:34:42 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8606 for debugger
[2012-11-17 12:34:44 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8638 for debugger
[2012-11-17 12:34:48 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8641 for debugger
```

My AVD has Google APIs (10) as target, and my project it's a simple project to test google maps. It has Google APIs [Android 2.3.3] as project build target.

Looking for a solution in StackOverflow I found this answer: [Should I worry about DDMS console log messages "Can't bind to local nnnn for debugger"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937532/should-i-worry-about-ddms-console-log-messages-cant-bind-to-local-nnnn-for-deb)

I did it, but i continue to have this "problem".
How can i solve it?

EDIT

[SOLVED]
Another important thing: I need to take the key from google to use its maps, but when I insert the fingerprinter and try to generate the key, google doesn't give me it.
How can I solve this other problem? maybe it is connected to the first one?

This problem is caused by JDK 7, the correct command to obtain MD5 finger printer is:

keytool -keystore **-v** C:\Users\USER_NAME.android\debug.keystore -list

Comment: delete old adb, and create new adb

Comment: Hi Sardor, can you give me some details? I'm a newbie of android.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318738/i-get-error-in-ddmscant-bind-to-local-8600-for-debugger-why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After many research, I discovered that the problem of the messages "Can't bind to local..." is due to the version of JRE (the newest 7). It was enough to remove it and install JRE version 6.38.

Comment: Yes it is worked for me as well, but wondering how JRE 7 can be used on Windows 8, as I am getting this issue only on Windows 8 upgrade.